# python 2.7 difficulty with files

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I am attempted to create a program that counts the amount of animals (bear, wolf, etc) and put them into variables.

This is not working

```
import os
def count_species():
    sal_count = 0
    tro_count = 0
    filename1 = animals.txt
    if os.path.exists(animals.txt):
        f = open(filename1, 'r')
        for line in f:#will execute each line in the file individually
            if line == 'Salmon':
                sal_count +=1
            if line == 'Trout':
                tro_count += 1
```

For some reason the program does not register that the first line == Salmon. Everything else seems to work. An example of the file is seen below

```
Salmon
Trout
Salmon
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

You're reading the file in, and iterating over the lines of the file and checking:

```
if line == 'Salmon':
    ....
if line == 'Trout':
    ....
```

The line may not necessarily be this, it could have newline characters at the end (which it will here). Read the file in and strip the newline characters out.

One way to do this:

```
with open(path to file, "r") as f:
     lines = [x.strip() for x in f]
     ....
```

You also never close the file. Using the context manager you don't have to worry about closing it everything's handled for you.

Also, you probably don't want to be using two `if` statements here.

Comment: +1 for `with` and list comprehension - makes the code more readable, cleaner and more elegant. Consider adding a way for OP to not use two `if` statements there, such as using `sal_count = lines.count('Salmon')`.

Answer (score 0):

You may not see them, but your first line is not exactly the string `Salmon` only as it also contains ***newlines*** (or **"\n"**) which you get from pressing, say, ENTER.

Use [strip()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove whitespaces (that includes your ***newlines***) from a string, which in your case, is `line`. Change the following:

```
if line == 'Salmon':
    ...
if line == 'Trout':
    ...
```

into

```
if line.strip() == 'Salmon':
    ...
if line.strip() == 'Trout':
    ...
```

Also as @Pythonista said, always close your file. Add something like `f.close()` at the end or do something like `with open("filename.txt", "r") as f: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You could just see if that word is present in the line.

```
if 'Salmon' in line:
    sal_count +=1
if 'Trout' in line:
    tro_count += 1
```